# I cannot add the third row of GridLayout (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gridlayout

```
    <!-- Row 3 -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/missyou_kor"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:contentDescription="@string/missyou_kor"
            android:onClick="fade_5"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/missyou"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/missyou_eng"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:contentDescription="@string/missyou_eng"
            android:onClick="fade_5"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/missyou_eng"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loveyou_kor"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:contentDescription="@string/loveyou_kor"
            android:onClick="fade_6"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/loveyou"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loveyou_eng"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:contentDescription="@string/loveyou_eng"
            android:onClick="fade_6"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/loveyou_eng"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

This part is the third row of GridLayout.
My first, second rows are having same codes except for the srcCompat. 
I can see up to second rows, but once I add this third row part, what I can see is just the first row. (even second row is disappeared)

I thought the layout_width and layout_height had problems, but if I switch to match_parent or wrap_content .. doesn't look good.

[GridLayout - This is what I can see when I add that third row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfT4A.png)

[GridLayout - This is what I am expecting to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLeR1.png)

Thanks.

Comment: You should not set a fixed `width` and `height` on grid elements. You should use `wrap_content` instead

Comment: Hi Milk, thanks for your comment. So use 'wrap_content' on each elements for width & height instead of 150dp ? But just the first element becomes really huge and covers whole screen :-(

Comment: Your `GridLayout` should have width and height `match_parent`. This forces the grid to be at most the size of the parent (which is hopefully the screen size or less). If it still doesn't work you'll need to post more of your layout `xml` for context

Comment: @Milk Yes they're match_parent  :) 

I have quick another question; it didn't work for few hours like I mentioned on my question, but working now with the exact same code. The emulator was working well as well, but this situation happened a few times before when I was working with Android Studio. Do you have any clue that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I avoid using the `instant run` feature in Android Studio for these same fears, but have never actually had a problem. If you are doubtful, you can uninstall the application on the virtual device and create it again. It's always good practice to completely exit the program before re-running a change https://www.tomsguide.com/us/close-android-apps,news-21281.html

Comment: @Milk I get it. I'll do that. Thanks for your advice :)